# query of calculate the annual profit growth in qlikview by using text object

Tags: function, qlikview

I want to calculate the annual average profit growth rate for 5 years by using a text object.  Qlikview does not seem to support nested aggregation... I am new to QlikView, can anyone can help me?

```
Tried query:

='Annual Growth Rate  (2003-2007)  :' & avg((sum(Profit_per_Product)/sum(Total_Retail_Price))*100)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please exactly describe what you need. And it would help if you would add some inline test data.

Comment: @smartmeta hi,  I want to show the average profit rate  for example for 5 years : 3% , 5%, 3% , 5%, 4% . then in the text object i want to  show is  "Annual Growth Rate  (2003-2007)  : 4 % "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QlikView does support nested aggregation and can fulfil your requirements if you utilise the `AGGR` function. This function allows you to perform aggregation over a set of dimensions that you specify and in its simplest form, can be use as follows:

```
=aggr(expression,dimension)
```

This means that `expression` is evaluated for each value of `dimension`. For example, in your case if you used `sum(Profit_per_Product)/sum(Total_Retail_Price)` as your expression, and used your dimension that contained your data's *year*, then aggr would result in five different values (one for each change in your year). As you wish to take the average, then the `AVG` function happily takes these five values and provides you with your desired result.

Therefore, all you need to do is to slightly change your expression to the following (here I assumed that your dimension that contains the year is named `Year`):

```
='Annual Growth Rate (2003-2007):' & num(avg(aggr(sum(Profit_per_Product)/sum(Total_Retail_Price),Year)),'0.00%')
```

I also added the `NUM` function to format your result as a percentage.

More information on Advanced Aggregation (i.e. `AGGR`) may be found in section 25.2 of the QlikView Reference Manual (in my copy it's on page 291).